# Using "ember new" missing package error

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I use ember-cli to create a new Ember application.
Command

```
ember new my_app_name --skip-git
```

Encounter errors:

```
error code E404
error 404 Not Found: @ember/test-helpers@^0.7.9
verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

My version:

```
$ ember -v
ember-cli: 2.16.2
node: 4.7.0
os: linux x64
```

Comment: It's not a lot of info. Does it say in what file error happens? Did you try to run `npm install`? Also, your node version is very old. Current LTS is 8.9.4 and latest is 9.4.0

Comment: This happened when I create a new application by using command.

Comment: You can try to update your node version and [ember-cli](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v2.18.0) version (latest is 2.18)